# Issue with printing correct row based on match

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using a function to iterate through rows of a csv (data_file) and it is intended to print the row which matches. The issue I'm seeing is that it always prints the last row from the csv instead of the matched row.

```
def read_ability(data_file, ability):
    with open(data_file, 'r+') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for i in reader:
            if i[0] == ability:
                printout = tk.Label(output, text=i, wraplength=500, justify=tk.LEFT)
                printout.pack()
```

The same principle used in a terminal window

```
def read_ability(data_file, ability):
    with open(data_file, 'r+') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for i in reader:
            if i[0] == ability:
                print(i)
```

prints only the intended row.

I'm interpreting this result as the tkinter attempt overwriting with every row because there was *a* match instead of just *the* match. Though, I'm unsure how to correct this.

I tried putting a break statement after the pack statement to see if it would stop after the match. It made no difference.

Adding the code that is passing the arguments as initial response indicated code was functional.

```
def open_file(data_file):
    with open(data_file, 'r+') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        next(reader)
        r = 0
        c = 0
        for widget in results.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        for i in reader:
            button = tk.Button(results, text=i[0], relief=tk.RIDGE, command=lambda: read_ability(data_file, i[0]))
            button.grid(row=r, column=c)
            c += 1
            if c == 10:
                r += 1
                c = 0
```

Comment: Works for me just fine

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the solution is below

Comment: @GeneBurinsky I do not have the rep to upvote, but have selected your answer as the clear solution. I really appreciate the time you put into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all came down to how you [call the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219721/tkinter-how-to-pass-a-buttons-text-as-an-argument-to-a-function-when-button-i) in `command`. The reason it kept returning the last ability because that was the last item in the loop so that was the value that got assigned to the command

Namely, if `u` is the ability then you pass the value of the button the function like this:

```
Button(results, text=u, relief=RIDGE,command= lambda u=u: match_values(u))
```

Below, I cleaned up your code a bit by separating the above into functions so that it is easier to read and follow;

This function loads the file and puts it into a list of tuples where each tuple is a row. This way you don't have to re-read the file

```
def load_data(data_file):
    uniq_vals = []

    # close off file connection before doing further stuff
    with open(data_file, 'r+') as f:
        # load file
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

        # convert csv to set of tuples (separate value for each column so if you have more columns, add more tuples)
        datalist = [(rows[0],rows[1]) for rows in reader]
    return(datalist)
```

This function is used to find the rows in the csv file that correspond to ability (=`u`)

```
def match_values(u):
    collection=[] # initiate container

    iterate each row and collect those that match ability
    for row in datalist:
        if u==row[0]:
            collection.append(row)

    # this just prints the above into a table
    ncols = len(collection[0]) # get number of columns
    nrows = len(collection) # get number of rows
    
    output = Tk()
    rows = []
    for i in range(nrows):
        #grid with a row offset (looks prettier I think)
        Label(output,text=collection[i][0]).grid(row=1+i,column=0)
        Label(output,text=collection[i][1]).grid(row=1+i,column=1)
```

This function ultimately executes by printing the unique `ability` in a grid when you press the button, it returns the rows that match that `ability`.

```
def make_options(datalist):
    # initiate list to save unique values
    uniq_vals = [

    # get unique ability values
    uniq_vals = set(list(zip(*datalist))[1])
    
    # initate option window
    results = Tk()
    r=0
    c=0
    offset = 0

    # make grid of buttons for each unique ability
    for u in uniq_vals:
        print(u) # for our reference
        # make button
        button = Button(results, text=u, relief=RIDGE,command= lambda u=u: match_values(u))
        button.grid(row=r, column=c)
        
        c += 1
        if c == 10:
            r += 1
            c = 0
 
# call the functions:   
datalist = load_data(data_file)
make_options(datalist)
```

#### Cleaning Up

Currently, the above does not close existing windows so probably want to handle that.

Comment: Hi @Gene Burinsky,
I appreciate you clarifying the blindspot on my question. There are 6 columns per row. The way I'm trying to write this is you click a category (button) and it generates a new button for each row. Clicking the button names after the row item you chose should then print (label) the full row for that item. As I have it written, all the buttons are named correctly but always print the final item description.